# Typescript: Type unwrapping properties of specific generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, type-constraints

I want to achieve a type that extracts the inner-type of all properties being a `Model<infer T>`, but leaves others untouched; something like this:

```
MyType<{ a: number, b: Model<string> }> // => { a: number, b: string }
```

I thought it would be as simple as this:

```
type MyType<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Model<infer R> ? R : T[P];
};
```

but when testing it like this:

```
const fnForTesting = <T>(obj: T): MyType<T> => {
  return null!;
};

const result = fnForTesting({
  name: "Ann",
  age: new Model<number>(),
});

const a = result.name; // unknown :( -> should be string
const b = result.age; // number -> works as expected
```

Does anybody know why "normal" properties are not recognized correctly, while the `Model` properties are? And how do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [here](https://tsplay.dev/WkDJPw) this solves your problem

Comment: @Filly thank you so much! If you write your solution as an answer, I'm going to accept it as I honestly find that to be better (quicker and more precise) than the current answer. Could you also explain why we need to structure it like you did? Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. If you need more information, why this is working and yours isn't. I could write an answer, but If you understand it, feel free to write it yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your Model class is empty, `Model<T>` is the same as `{}` (the empty object type). So when you use `T[P] extends Model<infer R>`, TypeScript cannot infer `R` properly, so it uses `unknown`. The reason why TypeScript doesn't back off and fallback to `T[P]` is because *all types are assignable* to `{}` except for `null` and `undefined`. Basically,

```
type T = string extends {} ? true : false;
//   ^? true
```

Now notice that when I add a property to your Model class, to make it non-empty, your original code works:

```
class Model<T>{
    value!: T;

    constructor() { }
}

// ...

const a = result.name; // string
//    ^?
const b = result.age; // number 
//    ^?
const c = result.date; // date 
//    ^?
```

This is because there is now a clear, structural difference between a string (or date) and a `Model<T>`, and TypeScript can now check if `T[P]` is a model and infer the type.

[Playground (changed Model)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=1&ts=4.7.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECyD2ATApiAPAFQHwG8BQ0h0AbmCAK7ICEAXNBgNx4FHDwB2EALgE7nBd4PABQBKaDmgBfPDLxcAngAdk9ZNwCM0ALzQARGABGe6MgAeXZO0QwcU6AH5oWugAZoAeg-P5y1RnUuACYdCXtzS2sYA2NHZ2g3T29XZkUVOAUMP0wsUPwiaABtAAVoAEt2aABrZAV4ADN6AF06DBKm0wsrGzgkVDQK+uQeaAAlXKdRhPp2pikmPDZOLmh69gAxIQDuCoBzUMxOyJ67LGF4QwArVtE6WEzs7B1c-KIeZC5yHkr2chAQKhzBZLbjQd4QP4rXRrTY8bZcPbCV6EdhgAC2yDoegAgux2HoADQsQiIMCWOjsZAAd2gABEycgxESCmBdpjoJSaQgUOhfmjDMMzqIiVJRMCOKCwKFwZCAHSojEMJLQbg8PZ4LwFAB6DkWEpWhml6jlrOQSs1fIFIw13iIOr1y2gwCNEJAXFlpMs5u8ntUNu1uqAA)

---

Filly's code works you're essentially checking if an empty object is assignable to a string (or date), which is invalid. This acts as a guard before trying to infer the inner type of the model.

```
type T = {} extends string ? true : false;
//   ^? false
```

That means `Model<unknown> extends T[P]` only triggers if `T[P]` is an empty object or `Model<T>`.

[Playground (Filly's solution)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=1&ts=4.7.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECyD2ATApiAPAFQHwG8BQ0h0w8AdhAC4BOArsBfFQBQCU0O0Avnt3hQJ4AHZNAzJKARmgBeaACIwAIznRkADwrJSiGAhTowpflmgB+aFIBc0AAzQA9PYt8hIsZQBMMuElRpDxqoaWjrySirmVrYOTjZ48QLCcPwYrpgmsvhE0ADaAArQAJak0ADWyPzwAGaiALrWen40pKWk8ADupCbqmtowGPm1ZqKDQb2hjejFVchU0ABKJubz0NakyABus6sjebUA3DyHeCTkFNBVpABijO4UxQDm3phjITA4nFhM8IoAVtYYFgNFJpbAyExZIhUZAUGhUEqkGggEAAQkOnGOp0o0GhECR51klxuVDujyYkMIpDAAFtkNY5ABBUikOQAGgIREQYE0a2Q7WgABFuchWOzsmAHnToOt+ZM0IjqYpZl8WOzOCxMWRsWBvLj8QA6Km0-YxaCUKiPPCObIAPVMJy150UuvEBolyBN1oVSrmVqcRDtDrOxBdeJAFH1XM0nqcUZEftt9qAA)

(you don't need Filly's solution if your Model class is structurally different from the `{}` type)

Comment: But if you have two classes with the same properties. They are structural the same. The safest way would  be to create a type like `interface Model<T> { [unique symbol]:never; value:T}`

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation only checks if the property type extends Model, but if it does not, it simply returns the original type without any modifications.

To fix this, you can update the MyType type to include a catch-all case that returns the original type for any properties that do not extend Model:

```
type MyType<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Model<infer R> ? R : T[P];
} & { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof Model<any>>]: T[P] };
```

This updated implementation adds a second mapped type that includes all properties that are not a Model. The Exclude<keyof T, keyof Model> expression is used to get the keys that are not a part of Model. The & operator is used to combine the two mapped types.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! IMHO the solution of Filly (see question's comments) seems a little bit more clean / precise, that's why I would rather accept this answer. But thanks a lot for help, I upvoted it :)